# Value error when populating a new column in a dataframe based on conditional values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a function that will populate a new column called `'BS_Trigger'` based on the values in another column in the same `dataframe` (`'cnms_df'`).

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
....
def bs_trigger(dataframe):
    dataframe['BS_Trigger'] = np.where((dataframe['PRELIM_DATE'] != None) and (dataframe['PRELIM_DATE'] <= today), "Yes", "No")

bs_trigger(cnms_df)
```

With the above code, I keep getting a Value Error thrown:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What am I doing incorrectly here? ***Note:*** If `cnms_df['PRELIM_DATE'][i] = None' , that value is a NoneType, not a string ***

Comment: Use bitwise operator & instead of logical operator and.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```py
dataframe['BS_Trigger'] = np.where((dataframe['PRELIM_DATE'] != None) and (dataframe['PRELIM_DATE'] <= today), "Yes", "No")
```

with:

```py
dataframe["BS_Trigger"]="No"
dataframe.BS_Trigger[(dataframe['PRELIM_DATE'] != None) & (dataframe['PRELIM_DATE'] <= today)]= "Yes"
```

Comment: Yep, replacing it with the bitwise operator did the trick. Thanks,